# New task not visible

Tags: pokemon-go

I have completed all the following quest:
A troubling Situation
Jump-Start Research
A Mythical Discovery
A Ripple in Time
A Thousand-Year Slumbler
Let's go, Meltan

After all this task completed, I could not find any new task i.e Pokemon GO World Tourism Day Research Task. Is there any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 6):

From the "News" item in the Pokemon Go app:

> Specially themed Field Research tasks will be available for a limited time during this event.

The world tourism day research tasks are not **special research tasks**, which show up in the Special Research menu (along with the ones you've named); they are special **field research tasks**, and can be obtained by spinning PokeStops (assuming you have an open slot for field research).